# WCF Service. How to return HTTP 500 response

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I have a WCF service which access the registry and return the value. I would like to return a HTTP 500 response in certain cases for e.g. when I get null values returned from the registry without any exception. Here is my code. Instead of returning "null" string I want to return HTTP 500 response.

```
private string baseKey = "SOFTWARE\\Action\\software\\Station";

public string GetCode()
{
    string Code;
    try
    {
        using (RegistryKey regKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine,
            Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32))
        {
            using (RegistryKey subKey = regKey.OpenSubKey(baseKey, false))
            {
                Code = (string)subKey.GetValue("Code");
            };
        };

        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Code) ? "null" : Code;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "null";
    }
}
```

how can I create this HTTP 500 response to return to the client?

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dif you tried this ?

```
throw new WebFaultException<string>("Registry key not found", HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
```

Answer (score 3):

If an exception bubbles-up to WCF, WCF will set the HTTP Status to 500 and return a Fault.

In other words, throw an exception to return a 500 response to the client.

Answer (score 3):

You can inject a status code, like this:

```
WebOperationContext ctx = WebOperationContext.Current;
ctx.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
```

Note: `InternalServerError` is the `HttpStatusCode` enumeration values that maps to HTTP 500.

Comment: Thanks a lot Karl. I found something similar to implement.

Comment: Great, glad you found what you needed. :-)